# Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR in insert statement

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  Title varchar(50),
  Director varchar(50),
  Year int ,
  Length_minutes decimal(5,2)

);
```

Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (1,'Toy Story','John Lasseter',1995,81) ;

INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (2,'A Bug\'s life','John Lasseter',1998,95) ;


INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (3,'Toy','John Lasseter',1999,93) ;

INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (4,'Monsters,Inc','Pete Docter',2001,92) ;

INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (5,'Finding Nemo','Andrew Stanton',2003,107) ;
```

Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (3,'Toy Story 2 ','John Lasseter',1999,93) ; INSERT I' at line 4

The insert statements after id2 don't work.

Comment: What's before the `INSERT ` statement? From the error message it seems like you're inserting multiple values. Probably you're missing a semicolon `;`? How about paste the whole query here

Comment: I already pasted whole query. the semi-column is there, but at a different line.

Comment: There's something else happening here or you would not get that error.

Comment: Well then, see this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DfwTYpTr8Xj3McLi9KZNZ/1  .. its a similar error isn't it? How about you paste our whole query in the fiddle and run it, see if it has error or not.

Comment: I have updated the whole insert statement here.

Comment: Your error looks like there exists some invisible or non-visible (like CHAR(160), for example) symbol which is incorrect in this code point. And try to double a single-quote char in a value to be inserted instead of quoting: `INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (2,'A Bug''s life','John Lasseter',1998,95) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Primary Keys cannot be repeated. If you are inserting the same one again that is an issue.

**MySQL table creation**

```
CREATE TABLE movies(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
  title VARCHAR(250),
  director VARCHAR(250),
  year TINYINT,
  minutes TINYINT
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Since the `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` that `AUTO_INCREMENT`s, you will have to label all of your fields.

**MySQL insertion** *(only use on first insert)*

```
INSERT movies (title, director, year, minutes) VALUES('Toy Story 2', 'John Lasseter', 1999, 93);
```

**MySQL update**

```
UPDATE movies SET title='Toy Story 2', director='John Lasseter', year=1999, minutes=93 WHERE id=3;
```

Comment: Each insert statement is for one movie with a different ID. I am not sure what you mean by updating.

Comment: Usually `PRIMARY KEY`s are generated dynamically with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. If you don't want to `AUTO_INCREMENT` then don't. In that case you could leave off the fields *(columns)*. Still, once a row is `INSERT`ed with that `PRIMARY KEY` you won't be able to do an `INSERT` on it. `UPDATE` if the `PRIMARY KEY` is already assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue from the `INSERT` statement is here:

```
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (2,'A Bug\'s life','John Lasseter',1998,95) ;
```

There are two ways you can do this either escaping the single quote with another single quote like `''` or replace the opening and closing single quotes to double quotes. Look at this two example:

```
INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (2,'A Bug''s life','John Lasseter',1998,95) ;

INSERT INTO Movies VALUES (6,"A Bug's life","John Lasseter",1998,95) ;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/DfwTYpTr8Xj3McLi9KZNZ/2

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 INSERT INTO Movies (ID, Title, Director, Year, Length_minutes) VALUES (3,'Toy Story 2','John Lasseter',1999,93) ;
```

Comment: If it was because of columns, OP would receive a different error like `Schema Error: Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. I think this is not that because the error is showing the whole `INSERT` statement. So it's probably something before the `INSERT`

Comment: Good one tcadidot0. You have sharp eyes! Its the third INSERT statement. So it must be the \' portion.